# xsl:for-each select=: two conditions

Tags: xslt

in xsl we can write two condition in cycle "for each". for example instead of

```
<xsl:when test="/document/line[
                   (substring(field[@id='0'], 1,3)='MAR')
                ] and 
                /document/line[
                   contains(substring(field[@id='0'],123,4),'0010')
                ]">
```

we can write it:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/document/line[
                         contains(substring(field[@id='0'], 1,3),'MAR')
                      ] and 
                      /document/line[
                         contains(substring(field[@id='0'],123,4),'0010')
                      ]">
```

Best regards

**Update from comments**

```
<xsl:for-each select="/document/line[
                         contains(substring(field[@id='0'], 1,3),'MAR') 
                         and contains(substring(field[@id='0'],123,4),'0010')
                      ]">
```

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="/document/line[contains(substring(field[@id='0'], 1,3),'MAR') and contains(substring(field[@id='0'],123,4),'0010')]"> maybe it correct?

Comment: I can't test it, but I would say that the approach in your comment is correct, while the one in your post is not. You can't select two XPath expressions in a `select`, whereas you can use the `and` operator within an XPath expression.

Comment: The second is correct. thanks for answer, I keep it in mind.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the question is "is it possible to check 2 conditions in a select attribute of a for-each" the answer is: **NO**.
Because

> The expression must evaluate to a node-set.
>   (from [ZVON](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/xslt_for-each_select.html))

Hence the data type of the select must be a node-set not a boolean value.

But, if you want to select two node-sets inside a `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:template` (the latter is better) etc., you can use the **union operator** (|):

```
<xsl:for-each select="/document/line[
                         contains(substring(field[@id='0'], 1,3),'MAR')
                      ] | 
                      /document/line[
                         contains(substring(field[@id='0'],123,4),'0010')
                      ]">
```

Comment: @Petras I also added a possible solution to your need

Comment: You wrote: _"is it possible to check 2 conditions [...] the answer is: **NO**._ That's wrong. You wrote: _"The expression must evaluate to a node-set"_. That's right. Also do note that your **node sets union** has nothing to do with the OP intents taking from comments.

Comment: @Alejandro mhm, could be.. I referred to the first 2 code snippets in the question. Edit my response if it's needed. Thanks!

Comment: My solution was to use union operator (pipe). Thanks for input!

Comment: This answer is actually wrong. The right solution is in the questions update.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle You or the OP should post the solution as an answer and remove it from the question. It will be easier for future readers to find it ;)

Comment: I think it would be better If you update your answer to include the correct solution since it already is the accepted answer. Another answer would look somewhat awkward...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I prefer if you post the OP solution as a different one because both solutions work and a future reader can pick the one he prefers.